# Resolve when Promise is Ready

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angular-routing

I am new to AngularJS. I need to make an asynchronous external call (some API) during route change and display new page content when this call returns some valid JS object, say `var MySpecialObject`.

I would delay the new view display for up to 3 seconds but until the object is ready. So if I get object in less time - more likely - I would want to show new content immediately.

1.Where is the best way to init the call?

2.How do I display the new view once I get this object defined?

I tried using route `resolve`. Below code is what I started with successfully but I do not think it works well with resolving a 'promise'. How to display the new view once I have the object returned to the page? In other words I want to cancel timeout when object is ready.

```
 app.controller('PageCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(next, current) { 
      //API call here
   });

 app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider
   .when("/", {templateUrl: "partials/home.html", 
             controller: "PageCtrl", 
             resolve:{
                        delay: function ($q, $timeout) {
                            var defer = $q.defer();
                            $timeout(function () {
                              if(typeof MySpecialObject !== 'undefined')  
                                defer.resolve('Resolve'); 
                            }, 3000);
                            return defer.promise;
                        }
                    }

             })
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add a delay. Since you are declaring the resolve function, the router knows not to actually navigate to the new route (and thus render the view) until the resolve promised is actually resolved.

What you want can be written as:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
       $routeProvider
       .when("/", {templateUrl: "partials/home.html", 
                 controller: "PageCtrl", 
                 resolve:{
                            yourData: function ($q) {
                                var defer = $q.defer();

                                // do some work that will resolve the promise

                                return defer.promise;
                            }
                        }

                 })
```

and the resolved data can be injected into the controller like so:

```
app.controller('DestinationController', function($scope, yourData) {
   $scope.data = yourData;
});
```

Comment: I am not too clear about how to resolve my promise. In my case, resolving involves making a call and checking for valid JS object existence. Where do I plug that functionality in the Angular way?

Comment: Where are you making the call to? Do you have an external REST service? Perhaps an angular service?

Comment: Thanks. I am not really in control of this call. I must call the function that fires the Ajax call and the only success check is existence of some JS object from the response.

Comment: ok, so you would replace the comment about with something like:

if (typeof theVariable === 'undefined') defer.reject('variable not set'); else defer.resolve(theVariable);

Comment: thanks. I see where my problem is. Your above approach definitely works if object is available right away. But what if this object becomes available in some short time, like in 0.2sec or 0.5sec depending on my call response. How do I handle that within "yourData" function? Do I set interval to check for this object?

Comment: You could certainly do that, but it would make for a bad user experience since navigation doesn't occur until after the promise is resolved. I am starting to think that resolving in the route may not be the best solution, however, in order to help, I need to know exactly what you are trying to do. You say that there is an ajax call that will be made (out of your control) that will set a variable when it completes. At that point, you want to render a view? What happens if the variable is never set?

Comment: Exactly as you describe: I want to render the view once variable is set. If not set within timeout limit, I want to still render the view. Clearer example would be: my view needs to display some ad from third party. I would call for ad and hold the view. Once ad comes back in response and I can validate the existence of JS object I would inject it into the view and render the view. If ad is never set within timeout I would give up by rendering the view without the ad. Note, that I do want to inject the ad after displaying the view because I need to avoid possible flicker

Comment: can you provide the code that actually fetches the ad? and how does that code know when to run, that is what is the trigger to fetch it?

Comment: It's more simple than it sounds: say I have a function foo() that makes a call to external JS script. The script responds with some JavaScript object. I can only check for existence of this object to know the response is back. I thought to call this foo() on every route change but wait for the script response before rendering the new view. That's all. So: on every route change I call foo(), wait for response, show the new view. Thanks!